# Scrape text from selected option from dropdown

Tags: python, selenium, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

How to get the text of selected option from HTML structure using python?

```
<select class="required" id="PPT" name="PPT">
<option value="">Paying Term</option>
<option selected="selected" value="0-10">0-10 Years</option>
<option value="10-20">10-20 Years</option>
<option value="20-30">20-30 Years</option>
<option value="30-40">30-40 Years</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Show what you tried as properly formatted code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

This should help u:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

html_soup = soup('<select class="required" id="PPT" name="PPT"><option value="">Paying Term</option><option selected="selected" value="0-10">0-10 Years</option><option value="10-20">10-20 Years</option><option value="20-30">20-30 Years</option><option value="30-40">30-40 Years</option></select>','html.parser') #Creates a BeautifulSoup object

opt = html_soup.find_all('option',selected = "selected") #Finds all occurrences under the option tag where selected = "selected" 

for x in opt:
    print(x.text)
```

Output:

```
0-10 Years
```